# Website does not load the new data

Tags: php, browser, web

The question is :I am using codeigniter framework to develop a website the website have a CMS so when I add or update the site from the CMS the changes not appear directly i refresh the page on my browser but the old version still appears, then I wait for 10 mins for the new site to appear. When I make a change on the code and make a refresh the change does not appear, even after a wait for while the change appear.

I don't know why.

I change the browser but the problem still exists 
and changing the computer the problem still exists.

Somebody told me it's a cache problem so then I cleared my browser cache but the problem still exists.

Then I have uploaded the site to another server, but still the same.

Where is the problem? Please help me.

Comment: If it really is not a browser cache problem, it could be a procy, or memcache.

Comment: MR.Burki can explain it for me please i didnt get it.

Comment: try restarting the webserver

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution

the solution is just to delete the cache folder from the codeigniter framework